# Is it worth opening an ISA at the moment?

Tags: investing, united-kingdom, savings-account, isa

I'm looking to open a long term savings account, something to regularly put money into but not withdraw.

I can't find an ISA or regular savings account which pays more than 1.5% and investment services don't seem something I could keep up with to reap the benefit from.

Is opening an ISA actually a good thing right now or should I take the risk and open a managed investment account?

Comment: I added a UK tag, but have also voted to close as this is way too opinion-based as it stands. I am not sure whether it can be edited to be answerable here - specific product recommendation questions are also off-topic here.

Comment: 'An ISA' is a tax wrapper not a savings account. In an ISA you can hold stocks and shares as well as cash. The question should be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, as pointed out in comments, an ISA is technically a *wrapper* around either a "cash" savings account, or a stocks and shares investment product. So, the decision between cash and investment is separate from the decision between an ISA and non-ISA product. Similarly, regular savings accounts are just a category of savings accounts with particular limits on what you can put in them and when; I'm not aware of any "regular saver cash ISAs", but in principle I believe they could exist.

The cost-benefit trade-off of choosing an ISA product *as compared to a non-ISA product of the same type* comes down to two factors:

1. What, if any, tax savings will the ISA wrapper give you.
2. What rate of return is offered by the ISA product you're evaluating, and how does that compare with the non-ISA product you're evaluating.

The first point in turn is affected by a few things:

- What income tax band are you in? The money earned inside an ISA is exempt from the tax that *you* would pay on it, which in turn depends on your total income.
- Are you likely to earn more interest over all than your "Personal Savings Allowance"? This is a new tax-free allowance, based on your income tax band, across all savings accounts (but not investments). It's based on the *amount of interest*, not the *amount of savings*, so low interest rates make it go further - right now, if you pay only Basic Rate income tax, and manage to put all of it in an account paying 1% interest, you'd need £100,000 to use up your allowance.
- Are you likely to benefit *in future* from putting money into an ISA? There's a bit of fortune-telling involved here, but since you get a new ISA allowance each year *on top of what is already in ISAs*, it can be worth moving money into an ISA just before the end of a tax year, to build up your allowance. This used to be more important when the limit was as low as £3,000 per year, rather than the current £20,000 per year.

That tells you how much the ISA will *benefit* you. To find out how much it will *lose* you, when compared to other products, there's no real alternative to surveying the market, which changes all the time. You just have to check sites like [Money Saving Expert](https://www.moneysavingexpert.com/) to find the best products in each category, and work out which one makes sense for you.